# Why onActivityResult intent is always null on getting all files access permission?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

On getting all files access permission I want to pass extra data with intent to `onActivityResult` even if the user didn't grant permission but what I get there is always 0 as `resultCode` and null as `Intent data`.

**The code for starting activity:**

```java
public void grantFilePermission(final String requestId) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        try {
            intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", mContext.getApplicationContext(). getPackageName())));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
        }
        intent.putExtra("requestId", requestId);
        mContext.startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mContext, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
}
```

The `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` part is not relevant here. `mContext` is defined as `FullscreenActivity` int other place.

And this is my onActivityResult method:

```java
void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 2296 && data != null) {
        String requestId = data.getStringExtra("requestId");
    }
}
```

Here I always get 0 as `resultCode` and `data` is null, My main problem is with the data being null I need the `requestId` here even if the permission isn't granted.

### Update

as @CommonsWare answered there is no result on `ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` and even if it where the `intent` on  `startActivityForResult` wouldn't be the `intent` on `onActivityResult`.

I managed a workaround to pass the `requestId` with using a hash map which the request code is the key and `requestId` is the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` is [not documented to return a result](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings?hl=en#ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION). Hence, you cannot use it with `startActivityForResult()` very well, since its result will always be `0`, and it will not contain any sort of result data.

> I need the requestId here even if the permission isn't granted

You put that `requestId` on the `ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` `Intent`. Even for an action that *does* return a result `Intent`, *that will be a different `Intent` than the one you used in `startActivityForResult()`*. Random extras that you put on the outbound `Intent` are not copied into the result `Intent`.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any other good way passing the `requestId` to `onActivityResult`?

Comment: @Zoli: Hold onto it in your activity or fragment that is making the request.